# Relation between 'N' of make -jN with the CPU core?

Tags: android, makefile, android-build

For the optimum build time for Android Source code building (or any other Linux Kernel Source code ) how does the CPU architecture(dual core, quad core) is responsible .Is there any formuali for it?Does it depends on the number of threads handled by each core?For a machine having **n** cpus having **m** core each having the capabilty of handling **w** threads per core?**n,m** and **w**?Any relation with them for 'N' of make -jN.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The rule of thumb I generally follow (I'm not claiming that this is correct or best suited for all purposes) is to use the number of cores + 1 as argument to -j (given the availability of enough memory). Thus, in your example this would lead to the product of n and m plus 1:

```
make -j$(($n * $m + 1))
```